# Topology by Munkres p.143 example 7

Tags: general-topology

I'm sorry that I don't know how to upload the context, I'll just write the example:

> Example 7. The product of two quotient maps need not be a quotient map.
>
> Proof: Let $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb Q$ is set of rational numbers. For each $n$, let $c_n=\sqrt{2}/n$ and consider the straight lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with slopes $1$ and $-1$, respectively, through the point $(n,c_n)$. Let $U_n$ consist of all points of $X\times\mathbb Q$ that lie above both of these lines or beneath both of them, and also between the vertical lines $x=n-\frac14, n+\frac14$. Then $U_n$ is open in $X\times\mathbb Q$; it contains the set $\{n\}\times\mathbb Q$ because $c_n$ is not rational.

I can't understand that why $U_n$ is open in $X\times\mathbb Q$ because it contains the set $\{n\}\times\mathbb Q$. Please anybody let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what $c_n$ is?

Comment: No, you *should not* write down more *here*. If the question is incomplete, then edit it.

Comment: I edited it. Appreciate for letting me know I should edit it.

Answer (score 1):

They are unrelated statements about $U_n$, separated by a semicolon.

- $U_n$ is open
- $U_n$ contains $\{n\}\times\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Then could you let me know why Un is open?

Comment: The "cheating" way is to use the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $X\times\mathbb{Q}$ inherits the subspace topology from $\mathbb{R}^2$ (they are the same, it just saves us from having to work with infinite union of product of open sets here).  Note that $U_n$ is the two pieces -- above both lines, or below both lines.  The piece "above both lines" is the intersection of four affine open half-spaces ($x$ to the right of $n-\frac14$, to the left of $n+\frac14$, above line of slope 1, above line of slope -1), so is open.  Similarly "below both lines".

Comment: I understood it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

To recap: $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $X^\ast$ is the quotient of $X$ by identifying $\mathbb{Z}^+$ to a point, with quotient map $p: X \to X^\ast$.

$i$ is the identity map $i: \mathbb Q \to \Bbb Q$, and the example is $p \times i: X \times \Bbb Q \to X^\ast \times \Bbb Q$.

He defines $c_n = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}$ for all $n \in \Bbb Z^+$, and he considers the lines $l_1$ (in the plane!) of slope $1$ that goes through $(n, c_n)$ and $l_2$ through the same point of slope $-1$.

$U_n=\{(x,y) \in X \times \Bbb Q: (x,y) \text{ not between } l_1 \text{ and } l_2, n-\frac12 < x < n+\frac12\}$

This is clearly open as the intersection of an open subset of the plane with the subspace $X \times \Bbb Q$.

The second statement is not the reason why $U_n$ is open but a statement we need later.

Comment: Dear Henno! Why did you write that $(x,y)$ not between $l_1$ and $l_2$? And how it is obvious that it is the intersection of open subset of a plane with subspace??

Comment: @ZFR See the comments on the other answer.